# Select an element (text) using Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, textselection

In one of my internal web applications, we have to select text in a webpage and click on the selection.  then a popup opens up with more options.  This is a repetitive task for me and I want to automate it but selecting a web element as we do manually is not working fine for me.

Since I cannot share the web app, I have taken a webpage accessible to all and tried to recreate the problem of selection.

I am trying to simulate manual selection using mouse click at the top left of the element, then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then again click at end of the element.
It's not working.  What is wrong with the code?

**Expected selection is attached as a picture:**

[image: Expected selection is attached as a picture]

**Next is my code:**

```
import selenium
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


print("program has started")
# Customary code starts
myDriver=selenium.webdriver.Chrome("D:\\Software\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe")
myDriver.set_page_load_timeout(60)
myDriver.maximize_window()
myDriver.implicitly_wait(30)
# Customary code ends

# opening website
myDriver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal")

time.sleep(4)

actions = ActionChains(myDriver)
element=myDriver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/div/p[2]")
actions.move_to_element(element)
myDriver.switch_to_active_element() 
time.sleep(5)
actions.move_by_offset(-(element.size["width"])/2, -(element.size["height"])/2)
actions.click()
ActionChains(myDriver).key_down(Keys.SHIFT)
actions.move_by_offset((element.size["width"]),(element.size["height"]))
actions.click()
#    actions.context_click()
actions.perform()
#    print(element.size["width"])
#    print(element.size["height"])
#    print(element.location["x"])
#    print(element.location["y"])
#    print(element.location)

print("end of action")        
print("Sucessfully came to the end")
#myDriver.quit()
```

Comment: Should the script select from the first occurrence of "Animals" to the paragraph end?

Comment: It should select the paragraph which is located with a xpath (its named element in the code).
I wanted to extend this code to select element only if certain text is found in the page.

Comment: I found a workaround for you, you can use actions.drag_and_drop() ; I'm thinking of an answer that could be usable.

Comment: One more question. I see that in your Expected selection , the picture on the right side is also selected; But the xpath you provided does not contain that picture nor the text above or below it. Was that a mistake or the selection sould also include that?

Comment: Sorry, the picture should not be selected and only the element defined by xpath needs to be selected.

Comment: Drag Drop will not work here as the requirement is just selecting an element.

Comment: I've tried with drag and drop and other methods and all of them worked pretty good, but it keeps selecting from the middle of the start element which is very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # calling a action method as A
        a=A(self.driver)
        # Click on text box and enter some text
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/main/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div").send_keys("amar")
        time.sleep(2)
        # performing control action
        a.key_down(K.CONTROL).send_keys("a").perform()
        time.sleep(2)
        # selecting the text
        a.key_down(K.CONTROL).send_keys("c").perform()
        time.sleep(5)
        #click on bold and appl
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/main/div/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/section/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]").click()
        time.sleep(5)
```